# Cannot justify elements inside coretoolbar

Tags: polymer

I am trying to justify some elements inside `core-toolbar`  but I cannot get it to work.

here is my code:

```
 <template>
    <style>    
      :host {
        position: absolute;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        box-sizing: border-box;
      }
      #core_card {
        position: absolute;
        width: 300px;
        height: 300px;
        border-top-left-radius: 2px;
        border-top-right-radius: 2px;
        border-bottom-right-radius: 2px;
        border-bottom-left-radius: 2px;
        box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.0980392) 0px 2px 4px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.0980392) 0px 0px 3px;
        left: 440px;
        top: 90px;
        background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
      }
      #core_toolbar {
        right: 0px;
        color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
        fill: rgb(255, 255, 255);
        background-color: rgb(79, 125, 201);
      }
      #div {
        display: block;
      }
      #core_icon_button {
        display: block;
      }
    </style>
    <core-card id="core_card" layout vertical>
      <core-toolbar id="core_toolbar" horizontal layout justified>
        <div id="div1">div 1</div>
        <div id="div2">div 2</div>
        <div id="div">Toolbar</div>
      </core-toolbar>
    </core-card>
  </template>
```

**Code result**

[image: error result]

**Expected result**

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that the content you place inside of the `core-toolbar` is being pulled into a child `div` inside of `core-toolbar`'s Shadow DOM.

```
<core-toolbar>
  #shadow-root
    ...
    <div id="topBar" class="toolbar-tools" center horizontal layout>
      <content></content>  <!-- your content is inside of here -->
    </div>
```

Your layout attributes are not being applied to this child `div`, so you don't get the layout you'd expect.

The easiest way to get the layout you're after is to tell the child `div`s to `flex`

```
<core-toolbar>
  <div flex>Foo</div>
  <div flex>Bar</div>
  <div>Baz</div>
</core-toolbar>
```

[Here's a jsbin example](http://jsbin.com/raziga/5/edit)

Comment: thanks robdodson for your response; with your solution I can justify the elements horizontally but I cannot place them at the center of "tall" `core-toolbar` here is a [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/jutavemoyoxi/4/edit) to show my case.

Comment: that jsbin is using medium-tall, which I think only supports top and bottom. To put them in the middle of a 'tall' toolbar you can give them all a `middle` class.  [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/jutavemoyoxi/6/edit)